# Doubly Linked List Implementation and reusing iteration code

Tags: java, linked-list

I have my own implementation of a doubly linked list. For each property inside of the node, I have a separate method to loop through the linked list. I'd like to have a single method that accepts a comparator in order to stop the iteration over the linked list. An example of how I'm visioning it is this: Pseudo-code: `list.find((a, b) -> a == b)`. This method will find one node, however what if I'd like to find multiple nodes? Rename `findOneNode` to `nodeSearch(fn, bool stopAtFirst)` and use overloading?

```
public ListNode searchAge(int age) {
    return findOneNode((Predicate<Person>) node -> node.getAge() == age);
}

public ListNode findOneNode(Predicate predicate) {
    ListNode current = header;

    while (current != null) {
        if (current.getPerson() != null) {
            Boolean found = predicate.test(current.getPerson());
            if (found){
                return current;
            }
        }
        // Reached trailer?
        current = (current.getNext() != null) ? current.getNext() : null;
    }
    return null;
}
```

- Is the code above a good practice?
- Is there a better way to implement this?
- How would I, with good design, implement searching for one node, and multiple nodes in one method?

### Clarifications

When I say find multiple nodes, I don't mean return all the nodes. It'd like to use the `.toString()` method on each node, store that into a `StringBuffer` ,and return a string.

If there are 4 attributes on the node object (*First Name, Last Name, Age, Middle Name*) I need 4 different methods and do the same looping operation until I find the requested `Fname, Lname, Age, or Middle Name`.

Comment: It's probably simpler to create two methods - one for finding a single node (like you have above) and another for finding a list of nodes - since the logic for those two will be fairly different, even though some of the basic iteration code will be almost the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For each property inside of the node, I have a separate method to loop through the linked list.

Conceptually it's a bad design. It's not good cause it's not flexible. Even now you already have the requirement but you can't reach it.

In general, you should separate double list implementation from actual nodes payload (`Person` entity or so). If you think think this way you will realized that you can use any exist java `List<T>` implementation. E.g. `LinkedList<Person>`. So you can easily get nodes with persons fit in your predicate

```
List<Person> people = new LinkedList<>();
...
List<Person> sameAgePeople = people.stream()
    .filter(node -> node.getAge() == age)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

As a result you will have new `sameAgePeople` list with people fit your criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the line `current = current.getNext();` establishes the same result, and the `Boolean found` is superfluous, and could be in the test itself like `if(predicate.test(current.getPerson()))`

Depending on the desired genericity, your Predicate should probably be on the ListNode, instead of on the Person (you're mixing them up in variable names now)

As for better: it could also be done using recursion, which is usually a bit slower, but easier to understand (and if you're using Scala, it'll compile it to a for-loop).

As for searching for multiple nodes, that is something which is usually called a filter, which returns a collection of its own of the same type (so another linked list, with the same persons in it).